# Time evolution of perturbation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hamiltonian, perturbation-theory, time-evolution

This is from Noelle Pottier's book. I am unclear on how equation 15.1.10 follows from the information that she's given. Is the equation a consequence of inserting equation 15.1.9 in the commutator?

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The electromagnetic field is treated classically so the potential $\phi$ is a function of $\vec r$ and $t$ but not an operator. Therefore, $[H_0,\phi]=0$. In contrast, $\rho$ is an operator so
$$[H_0,\rho]=i\hbar\dot\rho$$
NB: Noëlle Pottier is a woman.

Comment: It did occur to me that that might be the reason but is there a rigorous proof for these cases where the perturbation involves an integral? Can the $H_1$ be taken inside the integral?